# Simple string replacement gone wrong

Tags: c#

I am trying to post a json string via a form submission ( multi-part encoding ) to an aspx page and send back a response based on the deserialized json string. ( I really need to do this via a form submission. no ajax )

I dunno why this doesn't work, but every time I try a simple string replacement to replace the single quotes with double quotes in the json string. It doesn't seem to be happening.

Here's a summary of what I did.

Here's the JSON string,

```
[["\n 22.02 13:15 \n ","\n \n \n \n ","\n \n \n \n ","\n \n \n "," \n Vereina\n ","\n \n ","\n 35 000\n ","\n 24.03.11\n ","\n Taiwan \n ","\n \n ","\n \n "]]
```

To send it via form data I replace all the " quotes with ' quotes like this,

[['\n 22.02 13:15 \n ','\n \n \n \n ','\n \n \n \n ','\n \n \n ',' \n Vereina\n ','\n \n ','\n 35 000\n ','\n 24.03.11\n ','\n Taiwan \n ','\n \n ','\n \n ']]

On the server side I am replacing the new lines since I don't need them,

```
[[' 22.02 13:15 ',' ',' ',' ','  Vereina ',' ',' 35 000 ',' 24.03.11 ',' Taiwan  ','  ','  ']]
```

Then I use the C#  string Replace method like this .Replace("'","\"") on the above, and what I get is

```
[[\" 22.02 13:15 \",\" \",\" \",\" \",\"  Vereina \",\" \",\" 35 000 \",\" 24.03.11 \",\" Taiwan  \",\"  \",\"  \"]]
```

I am observing this in the quick watch window of MS Visual Studio, also while debugging the code.

Comment: Aren't double quotes escaped with double double quotes?  i.e. " ""blah"" " == @" "blah" ".

Comment: @benjer3 : so in this case, @"" == """ ???

Comment: Well the outer quotes don't count, so @"" still equals "".  But that other poster was also right in that you need to write str = str.Replace("'", """") (that last part would be four double quotes).

Comment: Double quotes are escaped with slashes. Your `.Replace("'", "\"")` call is correct.

Comment: Oh whoops, you only escape like that when using @.

Comment: @benjer3 Oh yes, so they are. I'd like to amend my above statement to "Double quotes are escaped with slashes _except in a verbatim string literal_" :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The debugger shows strings as they would appear as C# string literals. That's why quotation marks are escaped. The string is not affected, though.

You can easily verify that by printing the string somewhere.

Quick demonstration:

[image]

In the debugging windows (purple) the string shows with escaped quotes (and surrounded by quoation marks, thus making it a C# string literal), while the output in the console (red) shows the actual contents.

Comment: Thanks man! :) I figured out the real problem was in the deserializer as well thanks to this.